# Multivariable Calculus - integral substitute method

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> $\iint_D e^{x^2+xy+y^2} \, dx \, dy$ such that $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+xy+y^2\le1\}$

The book answer: substituting method which, $u=x-y, v= \sqrt 3 (x+y)$

$\frac{v^2+u^2}{4}=x^2+xy+y^2 \leq 1$ then $u^2+v^2 \leq 4$

My question is, how did they came up with that substitution?

I tried doing $v=(x+y), u= \sqrt {-xy}$ but the jacobian went completely a mess

Comment: You're region D doesn't make any sense, the thing after the such that isn't a statement, please clarify this.

Comment: I edited the question by adding $\text{“}{\le 1}\text{”}$ where it belonged. $\qquad$

Comment: I would look up a graph of $x^2+xy+y^2\leq 1$ to see this. You could also complete the square and write this as $$\Big(x+\frac{y}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{3y^2}{4}\leq1$$ so $$u=x+\frac{y}{2},v=\frac{y\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ would also work nice as it transforms $D$ into then unit disc.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, I forgot to type it

Comment: @MatthewPilling so it's an ellipse ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the change of variable I used. What the book solution has used may be less intuitive but the idea is to convert the region into a circle centered at the origin. If we try and use change of variable which tries to make the region simpler, the Jacobian becomes more difficult.

Comment: Yes, it's an ellipse. Its major axis resides on $x+y=0$ while its minor axis resides on $x-y=0$. The expression $x^2+xy+y^2$ is called a *quadratic form* and can be expressed as $ (\begin{smallmatrix}
  x & y\\
\end{smallmatrix})\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 1/2\\
  1/2 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\big) \big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  x\\
  y
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$. The matrix in the middle encodes the major and minor axis of the ellipse $x^2+xy+y^2=1$. I'm not sure if you've seen this before, so completing the square is probably you best bet for these kinds of exercises.